# Finding $1/x^2 + 1/x^3 + 1/x^5 + \dots $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, numerical-methods, prime-numbers

The following function came up in my work:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1}{x^p}=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{1}{x^7}+\frac{1}{x^{11}}+\cdots.
$$

Naturally, this converges for $x>1$ since the geometric series does. Does this function have a name? Is there a better way to calculate it than the straightforward sum? In my application I can bound $x$ away from 1 if it helps.

Comment: It is related with an exponential sum over primes (see Vinogradov) through the substitution $x=e^{\pm u}$ or $x=e^{\pm iu}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Yes -- but crucially in my case, there is no cancellation and the magnitudes are not 1.

Comment: Naturally, I'm curious, where did this function come up in your work? I can't guess any application for it. Especially if you know no other form (i.e. an integral)

Comment: Has anyone calculated `f(2)` and compare it to common constants?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It's https://oeis.org/A051006 for what it's worth.

Comment: If you define the series for x<1 by reversing the fractions and get $\sum_{p prime} x^p$, than at least you get rid of the fractions. Beyond that it seems quite complicated as little is known about the distribution of the primes. I could only say it's smaller than $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: For integer $x$ this is the fractional digit expansion that is 1 in prime positions, 0 otherwise.

Comment: You could use prime gaps, and get tighter bounds on the sum. It depends on how exact you want the sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values of your function $f$ at positive integers $n$ correspond to the base-$n$ representations of the [prime constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_constant).

Indeed, $f$ is closely related to the characteristic function of the prime numbers. For instance, $f(2)$ evaluates to the prime constant $\rho$, defined as:

$$
\rho =\sum _{{p}}{\frac  {1}{2^{p}}}=\sum _{{n=1}}^{\infty }{\frac  {\chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(n)}{2^{n}}},
$$

where $\chi_\mathbb{P}$ is the characteristic function of the primes, i.e., the function such that for positive integer $n$:

$$
{\displaystyle \chi_\mathbb{P}(n):={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if }}x\in \mathbb{P},\\0&{\text{if }}x\notin \mathbb{P},\end{cases}}}
$$

where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of prime numbers.

The decimal expansion of $\rho$ begins with:
\begin{align}
\rho&=0.414682509851111660248109622\ldots \\
&=0.011010100010100010_2.
\end{align}

and is included in the OEIS as sequence [A051006](https://oeis.org/A051006).

The values of $f$ for other integers $n$ correspond simply to the base-$n$ representations of the prime constant. If we denote by $\rho_n$ the base-$n$ representation of $\rho$, we have:

\begin{align}
f(3)=\sum _{{p}}{\frac  {1}{3^{p}}}&=\rho_3 \\
&=0.011010100010100010_3 \\
&=0.152726266\ldots...
\end{align}

Therefore $f(n)=\rho_n$ for positive integers $n$.